# Decimal expansion of real number

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x$ be positive real number and $n_0$ be the largest integer such that $n_0\leqslant x$. Let $n_1$ be the largest integer such that $n_1\leqslant 10(x-n_0)$ and we can proceed this process. We got the set of numbers $S$ whose elements are $n_0, n_0+\dfrac{n_1}{10},n_0+\dfrac{n_1}{10}+\dfrac{n_2}{10^2},\dots$. I want to prove that $\sup S=x$.

1) Obvious that any of these numbers are less that $x$.

2) How to prove that for any $\varepsilon>0$ exists $E_m$ such that $E_m>x-\varepsilon$ where $E_m=\sum \limits_{k=0}^{m}\dfrac{n_k}{10^k}$?

Comment: Can you use induction to prove that $x-E_m<10^{-m}$?

Comment: Think of it instead as $\epsilon>x-E_m\ge 0$.

Comment: How to choose $m$ if we know $\varepsilon$?

Comment: It's obvious. $n_0$ is the largest integer such that $n_0\leqslant x$. Also $n_0+\frac{n_1}{10}\leqslant x$. What you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Base Case: Since $n_0$ is the largest integer less than or equal to $x$, $x-n_0<1$.  Since $E_0=n_0$, $x-E_0<10^0$.

Base Case: Since $n_1$ is the largest integer less than or equal to $10(x-n_0)$, we know that $10(x-n_0)-n_1<1$.  Dividing by $10$, it follows that 
$$
x-\left(n_0+\frac{n_1}{10}\right)<\frac{1}{10}.
$$ 
In other words, $x-E_1<10^{-1}$.

Inductive Case: Since $n_{m+1}$ is the largest integer less than or equal to $10^{m+1}(x-E_m)$, we know that $10^{m+1}(x-E_m)-n_{m+1}<1$, using this, you can prove that $x-E_{m+1}<10^{-(m+1)}.$

Now, if you choose $m$ large enough so that $10^{-m}<\epsilon$, then you can put the proof together.  (Hint: Use a logarithm.)

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!